# Is it true that the amount of debt is (always) equal to the amount of credit?

Tags: economics

I recently noticed critics of our financial system state that the amount of debts is always equal to the amount of debts.
Is this true?
I have so far only found German-language sources for this claim, seemingly based on the opinion of a single person, naming it the "fundamental theorem of economics". See [here](http://peter.fleissner.org/Transform/Gloetzl1.pdf) or [here](http://www.banken-in-die-schranken.org/vwl-grundlagen).
I however can't find any foundation for this claim in economic theory.

Comment: Yes, the amount of debts is always equal to the amount of debts.

Comment: If this is a question about definitions and theorems within economic theory, rather than anything taking place in the real world, I don't think it's a good fit for Skeptics. Economics.SE may be better.

Comment: This isn't really a skeptical claim at all but a question about the definitions of terms in accounting or economics. As such it doesn't really fit here.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is a question about accounting or economics definitions not a skeptical claim.